# For loop with a range in function

Tags: python, for-loop, range, sqrt

Write a function called `printsquares(numin)`   i.e., takes in the parameter `numin`.  The `numin` becomes the upper end of a for loop with a range Thus:

```
for i in range(numin)
```

and as the for loop executes it prints the square of each i in the range.  Here is the run:

```
>>> printsquares(6)
0
1
4
9
16
25
>>>
```

This is what I am supposed to do for my question I just can't seem to get the square roots to print like in the example.

Here is my code:

```
import math
def printsquares(numin):
    for i in range(numin):
        print(math.sqrt(numin))
```

Comment: There's a difference between a *square* and a *square root*.

Comment: @ecatmur: and a difference between `numin` and `i`..

Comment: Square root is exactly the opposite of a square.

Answer (score 1):

You are always printing the square root of `numin` instead of the loop variable `i`. Just use the latter instead:

```
def printsquares(numin):
    for i in range(numin):
        print(math.sqrt(i))
```

Next, produce the *square*, not the *square root*; just multiply `i` by itself:

```
def printsquares(numin):
    for i in range(numin):
        print(i * i)
```

or you could use the `**` power operator to raise `i` to the power of 2:

```
def printsquares(numin):
    for i in range(numin):
        print(i ** 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the square root of `numin` each time instead of the square of each `i`. Change your `print` statement to:

```
print(i * i)  # I think this is slightly faster than i ** 2.
```

---

Demo:

```
>>> printsquares(6)
0
1
4
9
16
25
```